# android - libvlc - onNewVideoLayout not firing - what decleration would normally cause onNewVideoLayout to fire?

Tags: android, libvlc

I am converting older android code that used the MrMaffen vlc player to a newer vlc library. I've got it playing video - but it isn't sizing to the surface. That is handled in the onNewVideoLayout function - that isn't getting called. What line in the following createVLCPlayer function should cause the onNewVideoLayout to fire?

```
private void createVLCPlayer(String pPath){
    releaseVLCPlayer();
    try {
        // Create LibVLC
        ArrayList<String> options = new ArrayList<>();
        options.add("-vvv"); // verbosity. This has to do with VLC logging.
        this.m_libVLC = new LibVLC( this, options);
        //this.m_libVLC = new LibVLC( this, options);
        org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer.EventListener m_PlayerListener = new MyPlayerListener(this);

        if(this.m_shHolder == null){
            this.m_shHolder = this.m_svSurface.getHolder();
        }
        this.m_shHolder.setKeepScreenOn(true);

        // Create media player
        this.m_mpPlayer = new org.videolan.libvlc.MediaPlayer(this.m_libVLC);
        this.m_mpPlayer.setEventListener(m_PlayerListener);
        this.m_mpPlayer.setAudioTrack(-1);
        //this.m_mpPlayer.setSubtitleFile("");

        // Set up video output
        final IVLCVout vout = this.m_mpPlayer.getVLCVout();
        vout.setVideoView(this.m_svSurface);

        //vout.setWindowSize(m_svSurface.getWidth(), m_svSurface.getHeight());
        vout.addCallback(this);
        vout.attachViews();

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(pPath);
        Media m = new Media(this.m_libVLC , uri);
        boolean blnTabletHWA = g.getTablet_VLC_HWA();
        m.setHWDecoderEnabled(blnTabletHWA, blnTabletHWA); // Force Hardware Acceleration.

        m.addOption(":network-caching=" + g.getCCTVNetworkCaching());
        if (g.useTCPForCCTV()){
            m.addOption(":rtsp-tcp");
        }
        m.addOption(":no-audio");
        m.addOption(":rtsp-frame-buffer-size=150000");
        //m.addOption(":sout=#transcode{vcodec=mp1v, vb=1024, acodec=none}:std{mux=mpeg1}");

        //m.addOption(":live-caching=0");

        this.m_mpPlayer.setMedia(m);
        this.m_mpPlayer.play();
        this.m_esService.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                NativeCodeLogger.logVLCToFile(g);
            }
        });
        //this.displayProgressDialog();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Error creating player!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize if my terminology isn't correct - but any input would be appreciated. Please ask me any questions about it and I'll try to give you any information you may need to help. This activity implements IVLCVout.OnNewVideoLayoutListener and  IVLCVout.Callback. I guess a bettter question would be - if I am debugging and stepping through the above function (createVLCPlayer) at what point should the debugger jump to onNewVideoLayout?